# dynamic partition insert Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a problem inserting records into a table called `exam_51_final` using dynamic partitioning, this is my scenario:

```
create table exam_51_temp(
order_id int,
order_date bigint,
order_customer_id int,
order_status string)
stored as avro
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='/user/ccp/20180827/51/avro.schema');
```

When I print the output I have:

```
68878   1404770400000   6753    COMPLETE    COMPLETE
68879   1404856800000   778     COMPLETE    COMPLETE
68880   1405202400000   1117    COMPLETE    COMPLETE
```

Then I have my table `exam_51_final` created like this:

```
create table exam_51_final(
order_id int,
order_date bigint,
order_customer_id int,
order_status string)
partitioned by (order_month string)
stored as avro;
```

I activate dynamic partitioning using:

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

Then I finally try to insert records from `exam_51_temp` to `exam_51_final` simulating a dummy dynamic partition column in two ways:

**1)**

```
insert into table exam_51_final partition(order_m) 
select order_id,order_date,order_customer_id,order_status,(case
when order_id < 1000 then '2018-05'
when order_id >= 1000 then '2018-06'
end) order_m
from exam_51_temp;
```

**2)**

```
insert into table exam_51_final partition(order_m) 
select order_id,order_date,order_customer_id,order_status, order_status as order_m
from exam_51_temp;
```

The select query itself is going well, but I always receive the following error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException Partition spec {order_m=null} contains non-partition columns
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

Uff...I found the solution: The partition column name must be order_month, if I put a differente column name I receive the error above.